# Java copy + user input word program with stupid results

Tags: java

Just tried to create a program that lets the user put a word that will appear in a new .txt file every 3 words. Here goes the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    if(args.length != 1){
        System.out.println("Wrong amount of files");
        return;
    }



    try(FileReader fr = new FileReader(args[0]); FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("lorem ipsum1.txt")){

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)); 
        BufferedReader br1 = new BufferedReader(fr); 
        String str;
        char ch; 
        int count = 0; 
        str = br.readLine(); 

        do{         
            ch = (char) br1.read();
            if(ch == ' '){
                count++;
            }
            else if(count == 3){
                fw.write(" " +str + ' ');
                count = 0;
            }
            else{
                fw.write(ch);
            }

        }while(br1.read() != -1);

    }catch(IOException exc){

    }

}
```

Text is just a lorem ipsum. That's the outcome after putting word "word":

```
Lrmismdlrstae,cnettraiicnltiau word prlglttroolscnettri word prsupnisedei word lsmgaaiclsobdutiislgl.Di word rtasmnqeusmxmsjsoefctra.Cacusnmgai word
```

How to fix this?

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling `br1.read()` twice per loop, so it's dropping every second letter. Try this:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
BufferedReader br1 = new BufferedReader(fr);
String str;
int r;
char ch;
int count = 0;
str = br.readLine();

while ((r = br1.read()) != -1) {
    ch = (char) r;
    if (ch == ' ') {
        count++;
    } else if (count == 3) {
        fw.write(" " + str + ' ');
        count = 0;
    } else {
        fw.write(ch);
    }
}
```

Comment: It worked. In order to avoid double spaces though, the code also had to be modified this way:

                            if (ch == ' ') {
           count++;
           fw.write(ch);
       } else if (count == 3) {
           fw.write(str + ' ');
           count = 0;